# Loading raster to R from PostgreSQL via pgGetRast takes a lot of time

Tags: postgis, raster, postgresql, r, postgis-raster

I wrote R code in R Studio to load a raster (stored in PostgreSQL) to R. The database is stored here: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\

### The following versions are installed on the computer:

- R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
  Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
  Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
- PostgreSQL 10.0, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit
- GDAL 2.2.1, released 2017/06/23
- POSTGIS="2.4.1 r16012" PGSQL="100" GEOS="3.6.2-CAPI-1.10.2 4d2925d" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016" GDAL="GDAL 2.2.2, released 2017/09/15" LIBXML="2.7.8" LIBJSON="0.12" LIBPROTOBUF="1.2.1" RASTER

### The raster can be downloaded from this page:

https://opendata.swiss/de/dataset/das-digitale-hohenmodell-der-schweiz-mit-einer-maschenweite-von-200-m1

### Raster into PostgreSQL

I used this code to store it in the PostgreSQL database:

```
raster2pgsql -s 21781 -I -C -M "F:\GoogleDrive\DHM_200\DHM200.asc" -F public.dhm200_LV03 | psql -U postgres -d db_name
```

### From PostgreSQL to R

With the following script I access the database and load the raster. **Loading the raster takes more than 3 minutes!!:**

```
library(rpostgis)
library(RODBC)
library(rgdal)

con <- dbConnect(drv="PostgreSQL", dbname="db_name",host="localhost",port=5432,user="postgres",password="pw" )

dhm200 <- pgGetRast(con, c("public","dhm200_lv03"), rast = "rast")
```

### Load .asc directely

Loading the raster original with the following code **takes less than 1 second!!**.

```
library(raster)
dhm200<- raster("F:\\GoogleDrive\\DHM_200\\DHM200.asc")
```

### My questions:

- Is this normal?
- How can I make it faster?

Comment: Did you test with geometries? Are they slow as well?

Comment: i was interested to test this but no download available.

Comment: Hi Sam. You can find it here: https://opendata.swiss/de/dataset/das-digitale-hohenmodell-der-schweiz-mit-einer-maschenweite-von-200-m

Answer (score 0):

Got here from a random google search. Got curious/worried.
Takes about 2 seconds for me.

user  system elapsed
0.699   0.077   2.119

Version:
PostgreSQL 11.10 (Ubuntu 11.10-1.pgdg18.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0, 64-bit